# What is wrong with this template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is wrong with this template?

```
<div class="estaticas">
<div class="innerFrame">
    <h3>Cambia tus subscripciones</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="estaticas">
<div class="innerFrame"><br>
<div class="spacer15"></div>
<div id="registroIzq">
<%= error_messages_for :user %>

<%= form_tag '/subscriptions/updatesub' do %>

<br/>

Si, deseo ser suscriptor
<%= check_box_tag 'option1', 'yes', @ss.option1 %> <br/><br/>

Sí, deseo recibir las novedades del blog
<%= check_box_tag 'option2', 'yes', @ss.option2 %> <br/><br/>


<br/>


<p>
    <%=submit_tag t("update") %>
</p>
<%= end %>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Got the following error:

```
SyntaxError in Subscriptions#filename

Showing filename.html.erb where line #13 raised:

compile error
filename.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected ')'
.../subscriptions/updatesub' do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
                          ^
filename.html.erb:30: syntax error, unexpected kEND
; @output_buffer.concat(( end ).to_s); @output_buffer.conca...
                         ^
filename.html.erb:47: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND
filename.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #13):

10: <div id="registroIzq">
11: <%= error_messages_for :user %>
12: 
13: <%= form_tag '/subscriptions/updatesub' do %>
14: 
15: <br/>
16:
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the = from the end.

```
<% end %>
```